# Resharper warnings are not visible on marker bar

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

I use Resharper 8.2 with VS2013 Ultimate. I have checked for exmaple "Find unused variables" as warning (they have blue color), but they are not visible on Marker Bar. Errors, hints, suggesstions are displayed correct
On Marker bar I see some blue markers, but they indicate for NotImplemented exceptions and todos. Any sugesstion, where can I change setting for this?